# qt access function in GraphicsScene from MainWindow

Tags: function, qt

To learn Qt and C++, I played with it and created a very basic drawing app.
I understood I needed the use a GraphicsScene subclass to handle the mouse events, and now I can draw lines.

But how do I access a function in GraphicsScene (graphicsscene.cpp) from MainWindow (mainwindows.cpp)?
To try this, I created the below public function in GraphicsScene, to display the mouse coordinates in the MainWindow statusbar.

```
QPointF GraphicsScene::getMousePoint(void)
{
    return mousePoint;
}
```

More of the code, if needed:

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include "graphicsscene.h"
#include <QTimer>
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    qApp->installEventFilter(this);

    Count = 0;
    // A way to close the app, clicking actionQuit, without using a seperate function
//    connect(ui->actionQuit, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(close()));

    int Width = 3200;
    int Height = 1600;
    this->resize(Width, Height);
    scene = new GraphicsScene();
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
    int sceneWidth = this->width()-20;
    int sceneHeight = this->height()-160;
    ui->graphicsView->resize(sceneWidth, sceneHeight);
    ui->graphicsView->setSceneRect(0, 0, sceneWidth, sceneHeight);
    ui->graphicsView->setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing | QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform | QPainter::HighQualityAntialiasing);
    ui->graphicsView->scale(1, -1); // Coordinate 0,0 at Bottom-Left

    statusBar()->showMessage(QString("Size: %1, %2 ").arg(Width).arg(Height));

    scene->setBackgroundBrush(Qt::black);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

graphicsscene.cpp

```
#include "graphicsscene.h"
#include <QDebug>

GraphicsScene::GraphicsScene(QObject *parent) :
    QGraphicsScene(parent)
{
    this->setBackgroundBrush(Qt::black);
}

void GraphicsScene::mouseDoubleClickEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * mouseEvent)
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << mouseEvent->scenePos();
    QGraphicsScene::mouseDoubleClickEvent(mouseEvent);
}

void GraphicsScene::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * mouseEvent)
{
    mousePoint = mouseEvent->scenePos();
    QGraphicsScene::mouseMoveEvent(mouseEvent);
}

void GraphicsScene::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * mouseEvent)
{
    mousePoint = mouseEvent->scenePos();

    mousePoints.append(mouseEvent->scenePos());

    if(mousePoints.size() == 2)
    {
        QColor color;
        color.setRgb(128, 0, 255);
        QPen pen;
        pen.setColor(color);
        pen.setWidth(20);
        pen.setCapStyle(Qt::RoundCap);
        this->addLine(mousePoints.at(0).x(), mousePoints.at(0).y(), mousePoints.at(1).x(), mousePoints.at(1).y(), pen);

        mousePoints.clear();
    }

    QGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent(mouseEvent);
}

void GraphicsScene::mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * mouseEvent)
{
    mousePoint = mouseEvent->scenePos();
    QGraphicsScene::mouseReleaseEvent(mouseEvent);
}

QPointF GraphicsScene::getMousePoint(void)
{
    return mousePoint;
}
```

graphicsscene.h

```
#ifndef GRAPHICSSCENE_H
#define GRAPHICSSCENE_H

#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent>
#include <QPointF>
#include <QList>

class GraphicsScene : public QGraphicsScene
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit GraphicsScene(QObject *parent = 0);
    virtual void mouseDoubleClickEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * mouseEvent);
    virtual void mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * mouseEvent);
    virtual void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * mouseEvent);
    virtual void mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * mouseEvent);

    virtual QPointF getMousePoint(void);

signals:

public slots:

private:
    QList <QPointF> mousePoints;

    QPointF mousePoint;

};

#endif // GRAPHICSSCENE_H
```

Comment: Do you want to display the position while the mouse is moving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use the `virtual` modifier if you want to use this function.

You must change:

```
virtual QPointF getMousePoint(void);
```

to

```
QPointF getMousePoint(void);
```

If you want to track the object while moving the mouse I recommend creating a signal, for example:

**graphicsscene.h**

```
signals:
    void changedMousePosition(QPointF point);
```

**graphicsscene.cpp**

```
void GraphicsScene::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * mouseEvent)
{
    QPointF point = mouseEvent->scenePos();
    emit changedMousePosition(point);
    QGraphicsScene::mouseMoveEvent(mouseEvent);
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
public slots:
    void onChangedMousePosition(QPointF point);
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ...
    statusBar()->showMessage(QString("Size: %1, %2 ").arg(Width).arg(Height));

    scene->setBackgroundBrush(Qt::black);
    connect(scene, &GraphicsScene::changedMousePosition, this, &MainWindow::onChangedMousePosition);
}


void MainWindow::onChangedMousePosition(QPointF point)
{
    statusBar()->showMessage(QString("x: %1 y: %2").arg(point.x()).arg(point.y()));
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. I did exactly as your example code.


Though, I get a compile error at the line "connect..." in the constructor of MainWindow:
"error: no matching function for call to ‘MainWindow::connect(QGraphicsScene*&, void (GraphicsScene::*)(QPointF), MainWindow*, void (MainWindow::*)(QPointF))’
     connect(scene, &GraphicsScene::changedMousePosition, this, &MainWindow::onChangedMousePosition);"

Comment: Did you add the signal and the slot?

Comment: complete example: https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/GraphicsScene

Comment: Yes, I now used `connect(scene, SIGNAL(GraphicsScene::changedMousePosition(QPointF mousePoint)), this, SLOT(MainWindow::onChangedMousePosition(QPointF mousePoint)));`, but no luck. onChangedMousePosition isn't called, yet.

Comment: I have shared the link of my project, but if you still have no luck you could share your project via github, dropbox, drive or similar.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Mine is here now: https://github.com/JackBerkhout/QT_Draw001
Note: the windows size may be somewhat big, I use a 4k linux laptop.

Comment: In the mainwindow.h file you should change `QGraphicsScene *graphicsScene` to `GraphicsScene *graphicsScene`

Comment: Thanks eyllanesc, I will do so. I updated github.com/JackBerkhout/QT_Draw001 so other people can use it as a working example. I will probably extend it a bit more and play with it to learn more.
How do I mark it correct?

Comment: Next to my question there is an icon of votes, there is a check in gray.

Comment: I added a Line subclass from the GraphicsScene class , to draw a line.
From MainWindow I call the line function in that class, there are no errors, but the line isn't drawn. I know this must be lack of my c++ skills. But searching didn't help me on this one. What I want is to make different classes for drawing different shapes, instead of polluting the GraphicsScene with all that code, to keep things a bit structured.
But what am I doing wrong? I posted my code on github https://github.com/JackBerkhout/QT_Draw001

Answer (score 0):

from `MainWindow` class, if you have a reference to your scene with `scene` member, then you should just have to use it: `scene->getMousePoint()`.
Of course, the type of `scene` member must be `GraphicsScene*` instead of `QGraphicsScene*`.

Comment: Hi Nikazo, thank you for your quick response. I tried it, but had to use QGraphicsScene as QGraphicsScene*, it doesn't seem to exist. And then got the error: ‘class QGraphicsScene’ has no member named ‘getMousePoint’
     scene->getMousePoint();

Comment: Hi Nikazo, thank you for your quick response.
I finally got it working with:
    GraphicsScene *graphicsScene = new GraphicsScene();
    QPointF mousePoint = graphicsScene->getMousePoint();
    int MouseX = graphicsScene->getMouseX();
    int MouseY = graphicsScene->getMouseY();

Comment: I return a number in a function in GraphicsScene, and get it in MainWindow. In GraphicsScene, I increment the number in the MousePressEvent, but that doesn't increment the number. Number is declared in the GraphicsScene headerfile.

Comment: This doesn't increment either

GraphicsScene::getNumber(void)
{
    Number++;
    return Number;
}
What could be wrong? I have never seen this before.

Comment: Because of "GraphicsScene *graphicsScene = new GraphicsScene();", I'm calling the constructor and reinitiazing the variable. So I must try to do it different, but how can I do it? I must obtain a reference to it somehow.

Comment: I now used this, as it compiled:
`connect(scene, SIGNAL(GraphicsScene::changedMousePosition), this, SLOT(MainWindow::onChangedMousePosition));`
But onChangedMousePosition isn't called.

Also, I couldn't solve my original question, on how to call a function in GraphicsScene from MainWindow.
The solution from Nikazo doesn't work.

Comment: @Jack Berkhout, how is declared your variable `Number`?

Comment: @Jack-Berkhout, to see if a Qt connection is well established, that can only be checked on runtime. If it's not the case, you will notice a warning message from your application console.  Anyway, just don't forget to call `emit changedMousePosition()` as it's a custom signal, Qt will not do it for you.

Comment: Now I used `GraphicsScene graphicsScene;` in MainWindow.h, it seems to help. But once I click on the GraphicsScene, "The program has unexpectedly finished."

Comment: Thank you all very much!
One problem was that mousetracking wasn't enabled, so I had to hold down a mouse button to see it working.
eyllanesc helped me out. I updated https://github.com/JackBerkhout/QT_Draw001 so other people can use it as a working example. I will probably extend it a bit more and play with it to learn more.